# How can I create several PendingIntent?

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-pendingintent

How can I create several PendingIntent?
I have several notifications, and when user pressing to the last one, everything is ok, but otherwise clicking on the notification is not responding.
My code is:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).setAction("ShowDialog");
notificationIntent.putExtra("args", Tools.getInstance().generateBundle(progressId, lastId));
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
```

I suppose that the reason is FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT, but all flags of PendingIntent cannot resolve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my guess,

You just need to give different unique ID to each pending intent and there shall be no any problem in your application.

Like, 
`PendingIntent.getActivity(context, uniqID, nIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);`

---

If you are not planning to delete or update the intent then you can use `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` as your unique ID.

Comment: Am I missing something, or are you saying that setting the response code solves the problem? The documentation says it is not used. If that is the case, I would not trust this solution to work in the future.

Comment: @TobiasRitzau Each pending intent created stays in memoty until it get fired and also after it...and each have diff id..if you dont specify the id everytime you create one pendingintent..its just different object of same pending intent..to get diff many pending intent just making diff object not work..you also need to give diff id to each. Try it your way making a demo..and I am sure you will come and give the answer +1

Comment: I'm not saying that it does not work in the current implementation, but the according to the documentation this is not correct. Then you can not expect it to work in the future. Just saying :) I will see if I can find the info I have previously read on this and get back if I find something.

Comment: Ok, now I have taken a look at this. The pending intent wraps an IntentSender. The documentation states "If the creating application later re-retrieves the same kind of IntentSender (same operation, same Intent action, data, categories, and components, and same flags), it will receive a IntentSender representing the same token if that is still valid." Thus not mentioning the requestCode. The current implementation on the other hand uses the requestCode. This solution is not correct since it is not guaranteed to work in the future.

Comment: @TobiasRitzau Thanks for your keen interest to get to the correct answer and I too favor that. I will surely try to find some time and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the CANCEL_CURRENT flag it does what you have described. You have to create different pending intents for different notifications, otherwise they are considered the same. Look at the [IntentSender documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentSender.html) to find out what you need to do to create separate pending intents. My advice is to encode an id in the data. It can be extremely simple if you like, or it can have a meaning to identify the intent. Here is the snippet of special interest:

> If the creating application later re-retrieves the same kind of
>   IntentSender (same operation, same Intent action, data, categories,
>   and components, and same flags), it will receive a IntentSender
>   representing the same token if that is still valid.

The problem you see is caused by the fact that you reuse the same pending intent, and you cancel the previous one when you "create" a new one.

Note also that according to the design guide lines you should only have one notification of each kind (for example only one notification for new e-mail, new sms, ...) If there are several notifications of the same kind they should be combined into one notification. However, it is only a guide line.

You can find info on why the "requestCode/uniqueId solution" works in the current version of Android [here](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#getIntentSenderLocked)